# Replacing \ with / using the string replacement method in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a column count in a 500 csv files.

reading them into python wasn't an issue but the issue rests on how Python read them

from my understanding `D:/myfiles/folder/anotherfolder/1folder/2folder` is the correct way to input your filepath.

My script read it in correctly:

```
import glob
import os 
import pandas as pd
mycsvdir = 'filepath'
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(mycsvdir, '*csv'))
```

except for one issue

with the code above

I was expecting all my files to be directed like this
`D:/myfiles/folder/anotherfolder/1folder/2folder`
but now it reads in like this `D:/myfiles/folder/anotherfolder\1folder/2folder`

I'm trying to a string replacement on this ''

but this method:

```
csvfiles.replace('\',''/')
```

is giving me this error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: `csvfiles` is a list. You need to loop over it, performing the replacement on each element.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Windows understands both forward slash and backslash in pathnames, and there's no problem with mixing them in the same path.

Comment: `os.path.join()` always uses backslash, since it's the canonical format.

Comment: I also suspect that the \ may not be an actual backslash character, but rather the start of an escape sequence for a non-printable character, such as `'\t'` or `'\n'`.

Comment: Yes, you need to escape the backslash: `replace('\\', '/')`

Comment: In the code you provided, the `glob.glob()` function is being used to find all the files in the directory mycsvdir that end with the .csv extension. The output of the function is a `list of strings`, each of which is the path to a matching file.

Comment: There is *not any actual problem* with the `os.path.join` result: both forward slashes and backslashes can be provided whenever a path is needed. `os.path.join` uses backslashes because that is the platform's "native" standard, but forward slashes are recommended in code because they are portable and easier to work with. See the first linked duplicate.

Comment: As for the `.replace` call, the backslash needs to be escaped, but more importantly, the `glob` gives you a list of strings, not just a single string. If you want to do something to each string in the list, you cannot just do that thing to the list directly. I provided the other reference links for those two problems.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import glob
import os
mycsvdir = 'filepath'
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(mycsvdir, '*csv'))
csvfiles = [cf.replace('\\', '/') for cf in csvfiles]
```

Comment: You're welcome - please remember to vote up my answer and use the checkbox to accept it as "the answer"